# Rendering directed graphs in a browser

Tags: browser, graphviz

I need to render Graphviz DOT graphs in a browser. I also need some interactive functionality such as allowing node names to be hyperlinks.

I have tried using Canviz (Javascript renderer), but it doesn't handle large graphs very well. Many of my links also do not work on large graphs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

graphviz can also render .svg files which can be displayed by webbrowsers and can contain links etc

Comment: this is the solution i ended up using. SVG is pretty great for my purposes.

Answer (score 4):

It's not cheap but [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) should do what you need.

Otherwise take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747464/javascript-diagramming-tool) for some other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Do you generate the graphs on the server, or are you looking for a client-side solution? If the graphs are generated server-side, graphviz is able to generate html imagemaps. See the example here http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:imap.

Answer (score 3):

We build [this site](http://dirtyenergymoney.com/view.php?type=congress) with a combination of svg (exported from GraphViz) and javascript+svg for the interaction. The highlighting doesn't work in IE, but interaction still does, using imagemaps also generated from GraphViz. I don't know of any off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of the site you built? Visiting the link (even via the [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100903105700/http://dirtyenergymoney.com/view.php?type=congress) would not render any graph. Alternatively an image of a site which is still active would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give [Cytoscape Web](http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/) a try. Its parent project, [Cytoscape](http://cytoscape.org/), was built to visualize biological networks, but both generalize to any type of network. Cytoscape Web is a separate project that uses Flash as its engine, but is manipulable client-side through Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Hermann Stamm-Wilbrandt  implemented [a fiddler](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/) on top of 
[mdaines's compiled-to-javascript](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/) GraphViz implementation.